# How to turn off rerender after dowload the file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rerender

i want to turn off rerender component after download the file. How can I do this? I want to do this because it generates unnecessary API queries.

```
<a className="folder-link" href={item.sasedUrl} download>
    <span className={getIconClassName(item.type)}></span>{item.name}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're API query is in a useEffect hook, you can pass it an empty dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // API query
}, []) <-- empty dependency array
```

This will only make the API query on initial render. If the component re-renders, the API query won't trigger.

[Check out dependency arrays in the docs to learn more.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)